# Element focus jumping on setting it to empty

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

When I change the value of an attribute (that is tied to an input field using v-model) using a method, the focus jumps to that input field.

I have three fields (using v-for) to create fields and get the contact information of three users. I also have a checkbox called 'Apply to all' that applies the first field value to the remaining two fields if I check it. If I uncheck it, it removes the values from field 2 and 3. The method works as expected, however, when I uncheck the checkbox, the focus jumps from the checkbox to field 3. Is there a way I can prevent this?

This is the html I have:

```
<input id="applyToAll" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" @change="applyToAll"/>

<div v-for="(data,index) in users">
   <div :key="index">
      <input v-model="data.contactInfo.phoneNumber">
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the method I have

```
applyToAll() {
      if (this.appliedToAll) {
        const copiedPhone = this.users[0].contactInfo.phoneNumber;

        this.users[1].contactInfo.phoneNumber = copiedPhone;
        this.users[2].contactInfo.phoneNumber = copiedPhone;
      } else {
        this.users[1].contactInfo.phoneNumber = '';
        this.users[2].contactInfo.phoneNumber = '';

      }   
}
```

This is my data object

```
users: [
        {
          id: '1',
          name: {
            givenNames: 'SpongeBob',
            last: 'SquarePants',
          },
          contactInfo: {
            email: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
          },
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: {
            givenNames: 'Patrick',
            last: 'Star',
          },
          contactInfo: {
            email: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
          },
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          name: {
            givenNames: 'Eugene Harold',
            last: 'Krabs',
          },
          contactInfo: {
            email: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
          },
        },
     ]
```

I want the focus to remain on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply reset focus manually using `focus()` method on the `ref` object.

You will need to add `ref` attribute to the input.

```
   <input ref="applyToAll" id="applyToAll" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" @change="applyToAll"/>

   <div v-for="(data,index) in users">
      <div :key="index">
          <input v-model="data.contactInfo.phoneNumber">
      </div>
   </div>
```

And your `applyToAll` method:

```
applyToAll() {
      if (this.appliedToAll) {
        const copiedPhone = this.users[0].contactInfo.phoneNumber;

        this.users[1].contactInfo.phoneNumber = copiedPhone;
        this.users[2].contactInfo.phoneNumber = copiedPhone;
      } else {
        this.users[1].contactInfo.phoneNumber = '';
        this.users[2].contactInfo.phoneNumber = '';
      }
      this.$refs.applyToAll.focus();
}
```